# Why are there different types of "Team" menus with EGit?

Tags: eclipse, egit

What dictates which type of team menu shows up for my project? Is there a way to switch between the two?

1. very traditional git-ish (ie. without "Synchorize Workspace" option)
   [image: no synchronize]
2. eclipse team-ish (eg. with "Synchroize Workspace" option)
   [image: with synchroize]

#### Update

My git repositories view shows the following:
[image: git repositories]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following steps I have enabled the "Team" features for my project:

- delete project in Eclipse
- delete project on filesystem (including .git/ repository data)
- clone project into filesystem
- add local repo to "Git Repositories" Eclipse view
- in Eclipse, invoke an "Import Projects..." on the newly added repository, and "Import as general project"

Answer (score 0):

The second menu should be in effect when you have:

- [Configured Upstream fetch](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Configuring_upstream_fetch)
- [Configured Push to Upstream](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Configuring_upstream_push)

That is when your local repo knows what to fetch from or push to your remote repo.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. However, if I do a 'git remote -v' I get entries for my origin for both push and fetch, so I think this is already configured. Also, those menu options aren't available when in the "1st" scenario.

Comment: @jlb Does that remote translate into Egit remote push/fetch config options being filled though?

Comment: I added a new screenshot -- I think this means that Egit is seeing the configured remote.

Comment: @jlb so you only see the second menu when you activate the "Synchronize Workspace" option?

Comment: I don't see the "Synchronise Workspace" option anywhere in the 2nd case -- how do I activate it? This is in essence what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @jlb it seems to be visible when Synchronizing view: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Synchronize_View

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19811/discussion-between-jlb-and-vonc)

Comment: Ok. I'm able to bring up the Synchronize View without issue, however I'm not able to add my repository to that view.